# DC/DC converter 12V > 5V providing 400 Watts?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm not acquainted with electronics, so please be patient with me ...

I want to drive a large LED strip from a car battery.

Unfortunately, the LED strip requires a maximum of 400 Watts @ 5V.

Now I need some device to convert the car battery's 12 V to 5 V while providing a maximum of 400 Watts.

Can someone please point me to a device that allows me to fulfill this requirement?

Aside question: How long will a fully loaded car battery be able to provide the LED strip with power and still be able to start the car?

**EDIT:** @PeterBennett's and @DaveTweed's answer go into the right direction here.

Thank you for your valuable answers so far!

@DaveTweed: Yes, you are right. I'm using two 5m strips, each requiring a maximum of 200 Watts (no joke, manufacturer's data). Yet I do only have a single 86A marine battery. The strips are laid out in a star pattern and joined at the battery. Given that, what would the circuit/wiring be?

For testing purposes at home I want to use a power adapter, yielding 12 V DC from 220 V AC. At this time it's hard for me to find a matching power adaptor yielding 400 Watts. So I am worrying whether a battery will withstand such large strain for long.

I should add that what I'm looking for is supposed to be outdoor equipment, used below the engine bonnet. Size and cost should be minimal (the transformation unit should not be larger than a few centimeters).

Comment: You'll need to narrow this down a lot - what are your other constraints? Size? Cost? Efficiency? Isolation? Fault protection? Without a lot more details there will be no one answer suitable for this question.

Comment: And in addition to @AdamLawrence 's comment there is no answer to be given for how long the battery can last because you have provide next to no information on the battery.

Comment: Depending on the efficiency of the DC-Dc converter, you will be drawing 35 - 40 Amps from the 12 volt battery.  A traditional car battery (Group 24 size) should be 60 - 70 Ah, so you might get about 1 1/2 hours before the battery is considered "fully discharged".  I don't know at what point the battery would fail to start the engine.  Modern car batteries are often much smaller than Group 24, so would have less capacity.  You would be better to use a separate "Deep Cycle" (often called "marine" or "RV") battery for this application.

Comment: Easiest way of doing the electronics may be a 12V to mains AC inverter and a couple of old PC power supplies (or one big one - do 800W ones have 80A available on the 5V supply?)

Answer (score 5):

400W @ 5V is 80A. I'm pretty sure the wiring in your "LED strip" is not capable of handling this, so I'm guessing that you're actually connecting multiple strips together. Do yourself a favor and provide separate regulators and separate power wiring for smaller groups of strips. Perhaps 16 groups of 5A each. The input current to each regulator would be about 2.5A (if the converters are about 80% efficient), which can be handled by reasonably-sized wires with relatively little voltage drop.

Car batteries usually have capacities on the order of 40-60 Ah, or about 480-720 Wh. If you want to be able to start the car, you should use no more than about half of this capacity, maybe 250 Wh tops. This means that your could power your display for maybe about a half an hour, after you take the power conversion efficiency into account.